# display_errors in ini_set doesn't work

Tags: php

I have a problem with ini_set('display_errors', 'off').

To quickly give you a run-through I have two files in the same folder:

1) "php.ini", where "display_errors = on" is set.
2) "iniTest.php" which has the following code:

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'off');

$conn = mysql_connect('localhost','excamplehidden','examplehidden') or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);
$db = mysql_select_db('examplehidden',$conn) or trigger_error("SQL", E_USER_ERROR);

mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `FakeTable`") OR die(mysql_error());

ini_set('display_errors', 'on');
```

When I run this page in a browser I still get:

"Table 'examplehidden.FakeTable' doesn't exist"

Where I expect to get nothing because I want to hide errors.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: HEY! How come you accepted the wrong answer? -1 for such unfairness.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That error is from your `die` command. You cannot suppress a `die` by turning errors off, as you are explicitly echoing out the `mysql_error` to the screen before exiting.

You should use `trigger_error` in the same way as your `mysql_select_db` line above to remedy this:

```
mysql_query("SELECT * FROM `FakeTable`") OR trigger_error(mysql_error(), E_USER_ERROR);
```